# MapView application is crashing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I'm trying to make an Android maps app. As I'm new to all this I'm fiddling around with the basics so I decided to create a map, show a button and digital clock.

When I run the project the emulator loads however when it tries to load the app it force closes.

My `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <DigitalClock android:text="@+id/DigitalClock01"
        android:id="@+id/DigitalClock01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></DigitalClock>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="xyz_my_key" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my manifest I have added the `uses-library` definition

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

and I have also added the internet usage permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Why is it crashing?

last entry from error log:

> No command output when running: 'am
>   start -n
>   com.example.android.google.apis/com.example.android.google.apis.com.example.andr­oid.apis.MapsDemo
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on
>   device emulator-5554

Comment: sorry to sound dumb but how would i check that?

Comment: Post the last messages from your error log, otherwise we won't be able to find the cause of the problem, which could be almost anything.

Comment: If you've set it up using the tutorial on http://d.android.com then I bet your problem is that you have not sent a GPS fix to your emulator thus the application will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the new information instead of responding as a comment.

Comment: octavian how do i send a gps fix to the emulator?

Comment: checkout my noobs guide on how to get maps working : http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-display-a-map-the-easy-way/

Comment: thanks james but i still keep getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't setup the project properly. i've gone back restarted copied and pasted the source and hey presto it works